# Deploy asp.net core mvc behind NGINX that does SSL Termination - Redirects to non secure login page

Tags: ssl, nginx, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

When requesting the site via SSL and not authenticated https://example.com

I get redirected to http://example.com/Account/Login

I have NGINX running at the edge as a load balancer that terminates the SSL and proxies the request as http to IIS.

NGINX Config

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    listen 443 ssl;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://cluster1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

}

as you can see I'm setting the X-Forwarded-For and X-Forwarded-Proto headers

In my MVC app startup i have this in Configure

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto,
            ForwardLimit = null,
            RequireHeaderSymmetry = false
        });
```

I have [RequireHttps] attribute on my controllers.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

**Update .NETCore 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1.0:**

New update .NETCore 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1.0 seems fixed the issue

**Update workaround:**

Understand the root cause from answer https://serverfault.com/a/516382/379823

It works for us on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS / Nginx/1.10.0

Add map:

```
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $thescheme {
    default $scheme;
    https https;
}
```

and changing the proxy_set_header line to use the new scheme:

```
# proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $thescheme;
```

**Previous workaround:**

We got the same issue. We do workaround by NGINX redirect HTTP => HTTPS (will get double redirect).

When I just read carefully docs.asp.net again, it seems redirect HTTP => HTTPS is the only way this time.

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

See docs here [Securing our application / Configure SSL](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/linuxproduction.html#configure-ssl)

Comment: I ended up doing the same thing, but its not ideal because you get a double redirect in a lot of scenarios.